# How to set Flask blueprints to allow anonymous access?

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm working on a Flask application and don't see in the documentation how to turn off the requirement for a user to be logged in. We need to do this for some REST services coinciding
(possibly) with some pages that do require logins.

What's the best way to do this? I've scoured the docs and snippets and don't see how to turn off the requirement for certain blueprints. I'm getting 401 (Unauthorized) pages on all that I try.

Thanks!

Comment: What blueprints are you using? Flask does not come with anything other than the core by default.

Comment: Some custom ones we are writing for our application, which instantiates **LoginManager** and sets up a decorator for login required for some views of certain patterns, but not the ones I'm trying to get to work.

Answer (score 6):

Flask does not require any authentication by default. Usually you have to decorate your view functions if you want such behaviour. So your error is most likely within your web server configuration.